# Timer Listener Class number error

Tags: java

im getting an error in my timer listener class , I was hoping if someone could take a look, and explain what is wrong with it. Im getting an error when I add numbers+1. Also It appears the stop button isnt working.

```
 public class Main
{

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Odometer Program");
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    // Creates Frame and a array of textfields
    JTextField[] tf1 = new JTextField[3];
    JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();

    for (int i = 0; i < tf1.length; i++) // adds texfields to frame
    {
        tf1[i] = new JTextField(1);
        northPanel.add(tf1[i]);
    }
    JButton DriveButton = new JButton(" Drive Car");
    JButton StopButton = new JButton("Stop Car");
    JPanel SouthPanel = new JPanel();
    SouthPanel.add(DriveButton);
    SouthPanel.add(StopButton);

    frame.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(SouthPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.pack();  // sets default seize and width to the frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    //  Create the timer
    ActionListener timerListener = new TimerListener(tf1);
    Timer timer = new Timer(100, timerListener);// 100 for tenth of a second
    timer.start();

    // create Action Listener for two buttons
    ActionListener buttonListener = new DrivecarStopcarListener(timer);
    DriveButton.addActionListener(buttonListener);
    StopButton.addActionListener(buttonListener);
    StopButton.setActionCommand("Stop Car");
    DriveButton.setActionCommand("Drive Car");
    }

}

class TimerListener implements ActionListener
```

{

```
private int[] numbers; // array of numbers
private JTextField[] textFields;

TimerListener(JTextField[] tf1)  // copy position into constructor
{
    // copy array to text fields
    textFields = tf1;

    // new int to create integers, the same size of text fields
    numbers = new int[textFields.length];

    for (int pos = 0; pos < numbers.length; pos++) //
    {
        textFields[pos].setText(String.valueOf(numbers[pos]));
        numbers + 1;
    }

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    for (int pos = 0; pos < numbers.length; pos++)
    {
        textFields[pos].setText(String.valueOf(numbers[pos]));
        numbers + 1;
    }

}
}

class DrivecarStopcarListener implements ActionListener
{

private Timer myTimer;

DrivecarStopcarListener(Timer t)
{
    myTimer = t;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    String action = ae.getActionCommand();
    switch (action)
    {
        case "Drive car":
            myTimer.start();
            break;
        case "Stop car":
            myTimer.stop();
            break;
        }
}
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Does it work if you change those 2 lines to `numbers += 1;`?

Answer (score 0):

In your code here:

```
          textFields[pos].setText(String.valueOf(numbers[pos]));
          numbers+1;
```

You are incrementing numbers by 1, but not assigning it to anything. Also, numbers is an in[], which is illegal to increment. I believe you intended to increment a value of an element within the array.

Also, you never set any values in numbers[], so all elements default to 0.
Assuming you are trying to increment the value of each element in numbers,you would first need to setup numbers:

```
          numbers[pos] = pos; //? not sure what value you want here
          textFields[pos].setText(String.valueOf(numbers[pos]));
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, im trying to add 1 to every tenth of second, if  it would make it easier I could the rest of my code.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code that shows how numbers is supposed to get populated. Or clarify for me.. Are you trying to display in each textfield a value from 0 to the total number of texfields, where each textfield would show the next higher 1/10 of a second? If that is the case, then you would just replace your 2 lines of code with mine. If not, show me more code to work with.

Comment: Sorry for the wait here is the rest of my code. I am trying to add 1 to every thenth of a second on the odometer.